# Python: casting an integer into a datatime stamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, time-series

I am finding it very difficult to convert the following list `l`:

```
l = [0, 1]
```

into the time stamps corresponding to the indices of the following dataframe `df`:

```
                 dt  val
2017-11-13 00:00:00  8
2017-11-13 01:00:00  17
```

Ideally the result has to be:

```
l = [2017-11-13 00:00:00, 2017-11-13 01:00:00]
```

so I can identify these two timesteps in the plot of a longer time series that overlaps `df`.

What's the best way of doing this? My attempt fails miserably and I can't make sense of the correct timestamp format:

```
index1 = pd.to_datetime(str(df.index[l[0]]), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
index2 = pd.to_datetime(str(df.index[l[1]]), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

This throws the error:

```
ValueError: time data '2017-11-13 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

Comment: What does `print(str(df.index[l[0]]))` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need list comprehension with `f`strings:

```
d = pd.to_datetime([f'2017-11-13 {x}:00:00' for x in l], format='%Y-%m-%d %H')
print(d)

DatetimeIndex(['2017-11-13 00:00:00', '2017-11-13 01:00:00'], 
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

**Performance** (depends of real data):

```
np.random.seed(2018)
l = np.random.randint(12, size=1000).tolist()

In [48]: %%timeit
    ...: d = pd.to_datetime([f'2017-11-13 {x}:00:00' for x in l], format='%Y-%m-%d %H')
647 µs ± 2.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [49]: %%timeit
    ...: d = pd.to_datetime('2017-11-13' + 
             pd.Index(l).astype(str).str.zfill(2), format='%Y-%m-%d%H')
    ...: 
4.43 ms ± 22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, but here's one without an explicit loop or specifying a format:

```
L = [0, 1]

datetime = pd.to_datetime('2017-11-13') + pd.to_timedelta(L, unit='h')
```

Result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-11-13 00:00:00', '2017-11-13 01:00:00'], 
              type='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Your solution won't work because `str` does not work in a vectorised way.